# Select Nullable type in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox

My problem is simple. I want to select a nullable Type inside a combo box which is previously binded.

PS: Please do not supply any workaround, related to Modify my data, inserting a nullable inheritor or whatever related. Is there any straight forward way to achieve this?